# Regular expression for Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need to match these 4 urls in google analytics goal tracking using a regular expression:

- /signup/findMe/recurring/confirm.html
- /signup/findMe/oneTime/confirm.html
- /dash/find/recurring/confirm.html
- /dash/find/oneTime/confirm.html

I thought I could use some help from fellow experts here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you could simply look for [**`.+confirm\.html$`**](https://regex101.com/r/Tl1Wxz/1/)

Comment: I have other urls containing confirm.html. I'm afraid this won't work in my case. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Perhaps an easier solution is to add a custom dimension on those pages you want to track and then filter on that in Google analytics.

Comment: (.*)/find(.*)/(?!skipped)(.*)/confirm.html
This did the trick for me. I also added /signup/findMe/skipped/confirm.html as a negative match. It's been running on GA for exactly a month and the urls are matched correctly. 

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it explicitly

```
^\/signup\/findMe\/recurring\/confirm\.html$|^\/signup\/findMe\/oneTime\/confirm\.html$|^\/dash\/find\/recurring\/confirm\.html$|^\/dash\/find\/oneTime\/confirm\.html$
```

But depending on the rest of your URL structure you could probably find a shorter expression.

Try a tool like http://regexr.com/ to practice.